# Why do my DIVs render differently in chrome versus firefox?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox

I'm building a very simple webpage (just HTML/CSS). 
I've had some issues in how the webpage displays between chrome and firefox. 
The chrome displays things much smaller and they are in different locations on the screen.
I would like my two divs to sit next to each other in firefox, they way they do in Chrome. See images:
[How the code renders in Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k0Jm0.jpg) and
[How the code renders in Firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cCOdE.jpg)

I've *already put a CSS reset in my CSS*, *checked to make sure the zoom is normal on both browsers*, and *done all of my widths/sizing in em, or %*.

PS - I know I'm using IDs incorrectly.

Any explanation for why this is occurring would be helpful. Thank you!

Here is the isolated code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=true;">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="example.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="img/font-awesome-4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Merriweather:400,900italic,900|Lato:400,400italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
   </head>
  <body>
    <div id="pageWrapper"> <div id="contentWrapper">
          <div class="wrapper">
             <section id="checkList">
              <h1>Want to become an Interpreter?</h1>
              <ul id="services">
                <li>
                  Q: --------------------
                </br>
                 <span id="textHighlight"> A: ------------------------------
                 </span>
                </li>
                <li>
                  Q: --------------------------------------------------------
                </br>
                  <span id="textHighlight">A: --------------------------------------------------------</span>
                </li>
                <li>
                  Q: ----------------------------------
                </br>
                  <span id="textHighlight">A: -------------------</span>
                </li>
                <li>
                  Q: -----------------
                </br>
                  <span id="textHighlight">A: ---------------------</span>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </section>
            <section id="calendar">
            <h2>Upcoming Course Dates<h2>
              <ul>
                <li>January 22</li>
                <li>January 23</li>
                <li>January 29</li>
                <li>January 30</li>
                <li>February 5<li>
                <li>February 6<li>
              <ul>
            </section>
        </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
html, body, div, span, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
abbr, address, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, samp,
small, strong, sub, sup, var,
b, i,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    border:0;
    outline:0;
    font-size:100%;
    vertical-align:baseline;
    background:transparent;
}

body {
    line-height:1;
}

article,aside,details,figcaption,figure,
footer,header,hgroup,menu,nav,section { 
    display:block;
}
div {
    min-height:1px;
}
ul {
    list-style:none;
}

blockquote, q {
    quotes:none;
}

blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content:'';
    content:none;
}

a {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    font-size:100%;
    vertical-align:baseline;
    background:transparent;
}

/* change colours to suit your needs */
ins {
    background-color:#ff9;
    color:#000;
    text-decoration:none;
}

del {
    text-decoration: line-through;
}

table {
    border-collapse:collapse;
    border-spacing:0;
}


input, select {
    vertical-align:middle;
}
/*end CSS reset*/
/*end CSS reset*/
/*end CSS reset*/

/*BEGIN general page wrapper styles*/
#pageWrapper{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin:0 auto;
}

#contentWrapper{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
    clear:both;
    margin-bottom: 2em;
}
.wrapper{
    clear:both;
    position: relative;
    clear:both;
    width:70%;
    margin:0 auto !important;
}
/*END GENERAL WRAP STYLES*/

#checkList ul{
    margin:1em;
    padding:1em;
}
#checkList ul li{
    line-height: 165%;
    font-size: 1em;
}
#checkList h3{
    margin-top:.5em;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}
#checkList h1{
    font-size: 3em;
    color:#649FB3;
    text-align: center;
}
#checkList{
    width:50%;
    border: 2px solid #A9BDC4;
    padding:1em;
    border-top-right-radius: 5%;
    border-top-left-radius: 5%;
    display:inline-block;
    float:left;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

#calendar{
    float:left;
    display:inline-block;
    background-color:  #4A6E6E;
    padding:2em;
    color:white;
    border-radius: 10px;
    font-size: 1em;
    margin-left:3em;
    width:40%;
}
#calendar li{
    font-size: .75em;
    line-height: 150%;
}
#calendar h2{
    border-bottom: 1px solid white;
}
#googleCalendar{
    width:45%;
    margin:1em;
    display:inline-block;
    float:right;
}

#textHighlight{
    color:#4A6E6E;
}
```

Comment: a bit off-topic, but that `insert sql versus insert into` in the firefox search bar is hilarious

Comment: Why? I'm learning SQL.... >_> One of the sites I was learning on wouldn't accept INSERT INTO, which I thought was standard practice. So I googled it.

Comment: I see no difference between Firefox and Chrome. Second box goes to the bottom around 1600px width on both browsers.

Comment: Did you look at my photos? Is the issue that maybe my screen is much smaller than standard screen size?

Comment: Maybe scrollbar size matters (different on Chrome and Firefox), so if you maximize your window on both browsers actual width of the browsers may be different.

Comment: They are maximized in my screenshots.

Comment: Do you mean the nagivation/tab bar at the top of each browser when you say "scrollbar"?

Comment: Add a red border around each box. then add a blue border around the parent container of both these items. This allows you to see where the break is happening visually to know that the measurements from FF and Chrome are slightly different. Always add a couple pixels of padding into your design so you don't have unintentional breaks. (I don't see anything off the top that would prevent this from working right)

Comment: ok! thank you--I'll see if it works.